# Total rating and average rating star showing wrong

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to learn by doing some projects, this it helps me to learn better but I got stuck in between I am trying to display Average rating and total rating and Total reviews but it is not show correct result. I am attaching column image. Please help me to fix this

**EXPECTED OUTCOME**:- If you  check "Table column image" there is 4 row of review_text in which only 3 row contains  review but 4th one is empty then total review should be 3 and
If we don't count the 0, the average rating of 3, 5, and 2 is 3.33.

and total rating should be 3

[Table column image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK8ar.png)

Controller page

```
$sql = "SELECT products.*, products_attribute_01.*, products_attribute_02.*, products_inventory.*, pd_images.*,
AVG(products_review.rating) AS average_rating,
SUM(products_review.rating) AS total_rating,
COUNT(products_review.review_text) AS total_reviews,
products.*
FROM
{$dbName1}.products
LEFT JOIN
{$dbName1}.products_attribute_01 ON products.puid = products_attribute_01.puid
LEFT JOIN
{$dbName1}.products_attribute_02 ON products.puid = products_attribute_02.puid
LEFT JOIN
{$dbName1}.products_review ON products.puid = products_review.puid
INNER JOIN
{$dbName1}.products_inventory ON products.puid = products_inventory.puid
INNER JOIN
{$dbName2}.pd_images ON products.puid = pd_images.puid
WHERE
products.puid = :puid
AND products.status = :status
";

$result = $db->read($sql, $data);
        $data['row'] = $result;
```

VIEWS page

```
// Extract the calculated values
$avg_rating = $data['row'][0]->average_rating;
$totalRating = $data['row'][0]->total_rating;
$totalReviews = $data['row'][0]->total_reviews;

$maxRating = 5;
$fullStar = '<span class="bi bi-star-fill star-icon"></span>';
$halfStar = '<span class="bi bi-star-half star-icon"></span>';
$emptyStar = '<span class="bi bi-star star-icon"></span>';

// Calculate the number of full stars, half stars, and empty stars
$rating = $avg_rating <= $maxRating ? $avg_rating : $maxRating;
$fullStarCount = (int)$rating;
$halfStarCount = ceil($rating - $fullStarCount);
$emptyStarCount = $maxRating - $fullStarCount - $halfStarCount;

$stars = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $fullStarCount; $i++) {
    $stars .= $fullStar;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $halfStarCount; $i++) {
    $stars .= $halfStar;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $emptyStarCount; $i++) {
    $stars .= $emptyStar;
}

// Display the stars
echo $stars;

// Display total ratings and reviews
echo '<span class="review-txt"><a href="#">' . number_format($totalRating) . ' Ratings & ' . number_format($totalReviews) . ' Reviews</a></span>';
```

Here is what I am getting

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62S6Y.png)

Comment: Why are you selecting every column from every table? You are selecting `products` table twice. `products_attribute_02` shouldn't exist. Your query should `group by` something otherwise everything rolls up into 1 row. Also not sure about the `for ($i = 0; $i < *** $i++) {` why not just have SQL aggregation generate those counts?

Comment: @user3783243 please give example

Comment: Example of how to use `group by`?

Comment: @user3783243 no actually what you said I don't get it, that's why said.........And I joined all table because I want to show on product detail page

Comment: `AVG(`, `SUM(`, and `COUNT(` are aggregate functions. They should have instructions in the query for how they function. My presumption is that you would want `group by products.puid`. You should write the query in a db client first to verify functionality before moving to application. This is just adding complexity to your issue.